# What is the equivalent to PHP's print_r() in C#?

Tags: c#-4.0

I am unable to debug my post submitted data in browser like we do in PHP function:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Comment: Are you using WebForms or MVC? Both are part of ASP.NET

Comment: I am trying MVC. But it would be helpful if you explain both. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you don't need a pretty solution (I think you'd use this for anything other than debugging). Then you can simply do this:

**Webforms**

```
<h1>Posted values</h1>
<table>
    <% foreach (string key in Request.Form.Keys) { %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= key %></td>
        <td><%= Request.Form[key] %></td>
    </tr>
    <% } %>
</table>
```

**MVC (put in view file)**

```
<h1>Posted values</h1>
<table>
    @foreach (var key in Request.Form.AllKeys) {
    <tr>
        <td>@key</td>
        <td>@Request.Form[key] %></td>
    </tr>
    }
</table>
```

I hope that helps.